# ConstraintViolationException doesn't work for both DTO & MODEL classes at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have some validation annotations on both DTO and MODEL classes :

DTO :

```
public class UserDto {
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;

  private String email;

}
```

and MODEL :

```
public class UserModel extends BaseModel<Long> {

  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;

  @NotBlank
  private String password;
}
```

I want to test this method:

```
@PutMapping("/update")
public DTO update(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO dto) {
    return baseFacade.saveOrUpdate(dto);
}
```

And I've created a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class :

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionResponse> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException exception) {

    //initialize the CustomExceptionResponse here...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

If I'm trying to update a user using the DTO with a blank `firstName` field, the handler work as expected, but when the `lastName` & `firstName` aren't blank, I'm getting a new `ConstraintViolationException` in spring console and a `Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction` in Postman for the password field, even though the exception is handled.

Comment: What does BaseModel look like? Is there any contraint on the id field?

Could you add a bigger stacktrace?

Also you have unique column email. What database are you using? Could be that multiple null values for e-mail are not allowed.

Comment: It contains just an ID field.

Comment: If you can debug check the values of the UserModel(which I assume is the entity through BaseModel extension) instance just before saving. See if the values of the instance comply with the restrictions set on the Model (so is e-mail unique, are password, firstName and lastName not blank)

Comment: The problem is that once it pass the `@Valid` validation from the controller method, it doesn't work again for validations from the MODEL class and throws some Rollback exception. My guess was that I need to use `@Transactional` but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is thrown during saving. If you have `@Transactional` default logic is to rollback when theres a `RunTimeException`. The `ContraintViolationException` you are seeing is then wrapped in a `RollbackException` cause of that. This is done before you defined ExceptionHandler is fired.

Options:

1. Create an exceptionhandler for `RollbackException`. (really generic and not informative)
2. Create an exceptionhandler for `RollbackException` and check the cause. (a little better but more complex and dirty)
3. Create a layer before saving which has a signature with `@Valid UserModel`